# Scan filename and move to respective folders on a different server

Tags: windows-7, script

1. I have a folder (Students located in server A) containing 800 files, each has a unique identifier in the first 6 characters of the filename (e.g.Y9L-01_xxx.xlsx; Y9L-02_xxx.xlsx; Y9L-03_xxx.xlsx etc).
2. I have folders with sub folders where I would like to transfer the files. These folders are located in server B.
3. Each folder in number 2 above contains the same 6 character unique identifier of the filename at the beginning of the folder name (Y9L-01; Y9L-02; Y9L-03). There is a sub folder called 2014_Hockey under the folders Y9L-01; Y9L-02; Y9L-03;
4. I would like to transfer the files from the "Students" folder described in 1 above to each of the 2014_Hockey folder that is located under Y9L-01; T9L-02; Y9L-03 etc described in 2 and 3 above.

Effectively, I would like the script to match the first 6 characters of the file name with the first 6 characters of the folder names described in #3 and then move the file to the 2014_Hockey folder under that folder.

Example:
The .xslx file in \Students\Y9L-01_HockeyChampionship.xslx located in server A to move to Y9L-01\2014_Hockey located in server B

How do I do this?

Thanks

Regards
Rauri

Answer (score 0):

This should be easily doable with PowerShell. I haven't tested this myself yet, so you should try it on some sample data before using it on your real files.

```
Get-ChildItem '\\ServerA\Students' | ForEach-Object {$NewFolder = $_.Name.Substring(0,6); Move-Item $_ "\\ServerB\$NewFolder\2014_Hockey"}
```

You may see unexpected results if some of the files in `\\ServerA\Students` *don't* match the naming convention you've specified.

This will, for example, do the following:

`\\ServerA\Students\Y9L-01_HockeyChampionship.xlsx`
will be moved to
`\\ServerB\Y9L-01\2014_Hockey\Y9L-01_HockeyChampoinship.xlsx`

If you need to *only* move the Excel files, you'll need to filter the rest out by adding in `Where-Object` like this:

```
Get-ChildItem '\\ServerA\Students' | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq '.xlsx'} | ForEach-Object {$NewFolder = $_.Name.Substring(0,6); Move-Item $_ "\\ServerB\$NewFolder\2014_Hockey"}
```